# Finding program or process that is triggering reboot

Tags: process, raspberry-pi, raspbian, reboot

Every night at exactly 3:00a, my Raspberry reboots, but nothing I have done or am running has triggered this.  I would like to identify the "offending" process and disable the rebooting.

This is the current version:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster
```

I checked `crontab -e`; there's nothing that would trigger this. Other suggestions on how to identify what might be triggering what seems like a scheduled reboot?

Thank you.

### UPDATE

Output from `last` command:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/splitflap $ last
pi       pts/2        192.168.0.8      Wed May  6 17:42   still logged in
pi       pts/2        192.168.0.8      Wed May  6 09:34 - 17:34  (08:00)
pi       pts/1        192.168.0.8      Wed May  6 09:34   still logged in
pi       pts/0        192.168.0.8      Wed May  6 09:34   still logged in
reboot   system boot  4.19.97-v7+      Wed Dec 31 16:00   still running
```

### UPDATE

Output from `systemctl list-timers --all` command

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/splitflap/pickle $ systemctl list-timers --all
NEXT                         LEFT          LAST                         PASSED       UNIT                                             ACTIVATES
Thu 2020-05-07 08:39:00 PDT  5min left     Thu 2020-05-07 08:09:10 PDT  24min ago    phpsessionclean.timer                            phpsessionclean.service
Thu 2020-05-07 08:46:11 PDT  12min left    Thu 2020-05-07 08:31:11 PDT  2min 21s ago prometheus-node-exporter-apt.timer               prometheus-node-exporter-apt.service
Thu 2020-05-07 08:46:11 PDT  12min left    Thu 2020-05-07 08:31:11 PDT  2min 21s ago prometheus-node-exporter-smartmon.timer          prometheus-node-exporter-smartmon.service
Thu 2020-05-07 13:51:22 PDT  5h 17min left Wed 2020-05-06 19:22:06 PDT  13h ago      apt-daily.timer                                  apt-daily.service
Fri 2020-05-08 00:00:00 PDT  15h left      Thu 2020-05-07 00:00:12 PDT  8h ago       logrotate.timer                                  logrotate.service
Fri 2020-05-08 00:00:00 PDT  15h left      Thu 2020-05-07 00:00:12 PDT  8h ago       man-db.timer                                     man-db.service
Fri 2020-05-08 03:15:12 PDT  18h left      Thu 2020-05-07 03:15:12 PDT  5h 18min ago systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer                     systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
Fri 2020-05-08 06:24:39 PDT  21h left      Thu 2020-05-07 06:04:53 PDT  2h 28min ago apt-daily-upgrade.timer                          apt-daily-upgrade.service
n/a                          n/a           n/a                          n/a          prometheus-node-exporter-ipmitool-sensor.timer   prometheus-node-exporter-ipmitool-sensor.service
n/a                          n/a           n/a                          n/a          prometheus-node-exporter-mellanox-hca-temp.timer prometheus-node-exporter-mellanox-hca-temp.service
```

I don't see anything before 3a - there's the `systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service` that ran at 3:15a, but yet precisely at 3:00a, the system rebooted.

I'm new to systemd, though, so maybe there's other timers this isn't revealing? I tried `sudo systemctl list-timers --all`, but got the same list.

I also found the following in cron.daily; after reviewing each of the scripts, there's nothing that would trigger a reboot (albeit if I interpreted /etc/crontab correctly, the daily scripts would be run at minute 6 (but not clear what hour) anyways, not right on the hour.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/crontab
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name command to be executed
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
```

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls /etc/cron.daily/
apt-compat  bsdmainutils  dpkg  exim4-base  lighttpd  logrotate  man-db  ntp  passwd
```

### UPDATE with logger

The good news is that the modification to the command logged the request - see the last two lines:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/splitflap $ cat /var/log/user.log 
 <4 other lines removed>
May  8 03:00:01 raspberrypi reboot: Reboot requested but ignored: reboot 
May  8 03:00:01 raspberrypi reboot: Parent: root     15328 15318  0 03:00 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -c /sbin/reboot
```

Def feel closer, but I'll confess my lack of knowledge here on how to then take this further to identify the offending program or service - I didn't see either a process id 15328 or 15318 when I did a `ps -ef`.

Comment: What do the logs say just before reboot?

Comment: If you run `last` does is record reboot records for these reboots?

Comment: Added output from `last` - the `reboot` entry looks suspicious?  Or is that normal?  Re "What do the logs say", any log in particular I should be looking for?  The log of my process just records that it received a SIGTERM signal: `1110 received termination signal 15 (SIGTERM)`

Comment: Raspbian uses systemd now (I know because I laboriously removed it a few weeks ago). So, you have to check not only cronjobs but also systemd timer units. Also, crontab -e only show you per-user cronjobs, you need to look at the systemwide jobs in /etc/crontab and /etc/cron.*/ too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace `/sbin/reboot` with a notification and logging script it may help to identify what is causing a reboot. Here's one example of setting up such a script:

```
mv /sbin/reboot /sbin/reboot.REAL

cat >>/sbin/reboot <'x'
#!/bin/bash
#
logger -t reboot "Reboot requested but ignored: reboot $*"

# Identify the calling process
ps=$(ps -ef | awk -v ppid=$PPID '$2 == ppid')
logger -t reboot "Parent: $ps"

# Abort
exit 1
x

chmod a+x /sbin/reboot
```

When you call this fake `reboot` you'll get two entries in `/var/log/user.log` per invocation. For example,

```
May  7 16:06:20 pi reboot: Reboot requested but ignored
May  7 16:06:20 pi reboot: Parent: roaima   20862 20857  0 16:01 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
```

It may be necessary to apply a similar style intercept for `systemctl ... reboot`. This is a little harder because it would be important not to break other functionality. A script starting like this might be suitable for installation as `/bin/systemctl`:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
if [[ "$*" != *reboot* ]]
then
    logger -t reboot "Not a reboot: systemctl $*"
    exec /bin/systemctl.REAL "$@"
fi

logger -t reboot "Reboot requested but ignored: systemctl $*"
...
```

Comment: Thanks, @roaima - I've set that up, tested manually, and look forward to checking tomorrow morn. Will update with what I find; appreciate the help.

Comment: Thanks! Updated the modified script; will see if that catches the culprit overnight, but if not, I'll try the slightly more risky (?) `/bin/systemctl` script as well for the following eve.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying culprit was a `reboot` triggered by the root `crontab`; while I had checked there was no reboot via `crontab -e`, `sudo crontab -e` displayed a scheduled `reboot`.

Thanks for all the help & comments that steered me in the right direction!